# Flutter build ipa does not see a native package

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ipa, xmppframework

I am developing a chat app using XMPPFramework for ios, I was building archive without any trouble till the version 2.10.2 of flutter. Running the app has no problem either in simulator or real device but just building ipa is failing.

[Error log from Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOEpi.png)

I've done many times `pod install` or `pod update`, no result, I'm stack.

I am using:

- Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
- Flutter 2.10.2
- XMPPFramework 4.0.0
- Swift Native language

Comment: do you use in flutter from xmpp_plugin 2.2.0?

Comment: can you delete podfile.lock and pods folder in ios folder, and then you must run (pod cache clean --all & pod install --repo-update) in flutter terminal iOS directory,after that you must run or build again your flutter code. after that feedback to me

Comment: I don't use xmpp_plugin, I use the native XMPPFramework for ios